# synchronize Outlook Ribbon togglebutton with registry settings in VB.Net for an Add-In

Tags: vb.net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, ribbonx

I am building an Outlook Add-In in Visual Basic and I have a togglebutton in the ribbon that controls whether a setting is on or off. This settings is saved and retrieved using "GetSettings" and "SaveSetting" which saves information to the Windows Registry (to my understanding). I want the togglebutton the correspond to changes made to that setting as it can be changed in other places than just the togglebutton. My problem would be solved if I could access the value of the togglebutton and setting it manually but as I have understood it: I cannot access it as I am building my ribbon in XML. I have not been able to find a solution to this, can anyone help?

Side note: If I add my togglebutton to the taskbar in Outlook and from there toggle the settings, the togglebutton in the ribbon doesn't change to "pressed" mode. Perhaps this is something that can be fixed with any provided solution from anyone :)

Comment: Settings are not saved to the registry.  They are saved to XML files, typically in a path in %localappdata% (not designed to be easily navigated to).  It shouldn't be all that difficult to do what you want, though... the button should be bound to a backing variable which reads from the settings on startup and writes back to the settings when it changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `IRibbonUI.Invalidate` or for a single control you may use the [IRibbonUI.InvalidateControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.iribbonui.invalidatecontrol) method to get your ribbon callbacks invoked for updating the cached values according to the state loaded from settings.

For example, if an add-in implements the getPressed callback procedure for a toggle button, the function is called once, the state loads, and then if the state needs to be updated, the cached state is used instead of recalling the procedure. This process remains in place until the add-in signals that the cached values are invalid by using the `Invalidate` method, at which time, the callback procedure is again called and the return response is cached. The add-in can then force an immediate update of the UI by calling the `Refresh` method (VSTO).

You can read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: Thank you! It works but if I need to invalidate the button from outside the ribbon class, how do I do that? In my case I need to invalidate when a new inspector is opened which is controlled by the Add-In class.

Comment: The `onLoad` callback provides an instance of the `IRibbonUI` interface. You can access the `ThisAddin` property anywhere in the code, for example, `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application`.

Answer (score 0):

Do not rely on the button to store the state for you - whenever it changes, it is your responsibility to refresh the Ribbon (by calling `IRibbonUI.Invalidate`), which will cause Outlook to invoke your callback on the toggle button to determine its state. You just need to store the appropriate state in your code.